# SQLite - INSERT INTO SELECT - how to insert data of "join of 3 existing tables into a new table"?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, sql-insert

So the scenario here is, I have 4 tables in the database namely:

1. "question_info": 
   `CREATE TABLE question_info (
   q_id  mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
   q_type_id int(11) NOT NULL,
   q_options_id  mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
   q_category_id int(11) NOT NULL,
   q_text    varchar(2048) NOT NULL,
   status    tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   q_date_added  date NOT NULL DEFAULT '2013-01-01',
   q_difficulty_level    tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   PRIMARY KEY(q_id)
   );`
2. "question_options_info":
   `CREATE TABLE question_options_info (
   q_options_id  mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
   q_options_1   varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   q_options_2   varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   q_options_3   varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   q_options_4   varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   q_options_ex_1    varchar(1024) DEFAULT NULL,
   q_options_ex_2    varchar(1024) DEFAULT NULL,
   q_options_ex_3    varchar(1024) DEFAULT NULL,
   q_options_ex_4    varchar(1024) DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY(q_options_id)
   );`
3. "question_answer_info":
   `CREATE TABLE question_answer_info (
   q_id  mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
   q_options mediumint(9) NOT NULL
   );`
4. "trivia_data":
   `CREATE TABLE trivia_data (
   q_id  mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
   q_text    varchar(2048) NOT NULL,
   q_options_1   varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   q_options_2   varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   q_options_3   varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   q_options_4   varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   q_options mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
   q_difficulty_level    tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   q_date_added  date NOT NULL DEFAULT '2015-04-8',
   PRIMARY KEY(q_id)
   );`

So what I need is to, insert a data into `trivia_data` table.
The data is returned by this query:
`SELECT question_info.q_id, question_info.q_text, question_options_info.q_options_1, question_options_info.q_options_2, question_options_info.q_options_3, question_options_info.q_options_4, question_answer_info.q_options, question_info.q_difficulty_level, question_info.q_date_added
 FROM question_info JOIN question_options_info ON question_info.q_options_id = question_options_info.q_options_id JOIN question_answer_info ON question_info.q_id = question_answer_info.q_id;`

This query would return data somewhat like this:
[image]

I have already tried this specific query to insert the data:
`INSERT INTO trivia_data VALUES(q_id, q_text, q_options_1, q_options_2, q_options_3, q_options_4, q_options, q_difficulty_level, q_date_added)  SELECT question_info.q_id, question_info.q_text, question_options_info.q_options_1, question_options_info.q_options_2, question_options_info.q_options_3, question_options_info.q_options_4, question_answer_info.q_options, question_info.q_difficulty_level, question_info.q_date_added FROM question_info JOIN question_options_info on question_info.q_options_id = question_options_info.q_options_id JOIN question_answer_info on question_info.q_id = question_answer_info.q_id;`

But it always returns this error:
`near "SELECT": syntax error:`

Honestly I am a novice to SQL. So please try to explain as simply as possible.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thank You.

Comment: Remove the word "VALUES", then it should be ok

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need the `VALUES` keyword, as you are selecting from a query:

```
INSERT INTO trivia_data (
    q_id, 
    q_text, 
    q_options_1, 
    q_options_2, 
    q_options_3, 
    q_options_4, 
    q_options, 
    q_difficulty_level, 
    q_date_added)  
SELECT 
    question_info.q_id, 
    question_info.q_text, 
    question_options_info.q_options_1, 
    question_options_info.q_options_2, 
    question_options_info.q_options_3, 
    question_options_info.q_options_4, 
    question_answer_info.q_options, 
    question_info.q_difficulty_level, 
    question_info.q_date_added 
FROM question_info 
    JOIN question_options_info on question_info.q_options_id = question_options_info.q_options_id 
    JOIN question_answer_info on question_info.q_id = question_answer_info.q_id;
```

In general if you are inserting a record then the syntax is

```
INSERT INTO <tablename> (<column1>, <column2>, ..., <columnN>)
VALUES (<value1>, <value2>, ..., <valueN>)
```

If you are inserting the results the syntax is like this:

```
INSERT INTO <tablename> (<column1>, <column2>, ..., <columnN>)
SELECT <value1>, <value2>, ..., <valueN> FROM ...
```

As you see there is no `VALUES` keyword in this case

Comment: Tried that. Error: "unique constraint failed:trivia_data.q_id:"

Comment: I guess the data i am trying to insert might have more than one same values for "trivia_data.q_id".

Comment: @FreakPirate That's right, you will need to fix your query so there are no duplicates in this field

Comment: Can I remove the "PRIMARY KEY" constraint from "trivia_data" table? Will SQLite accept the query?

Comment: @FreakPirate It will accept the query, although having a primary key is usually a recommended practice. What you can do instead is to add autoincremented surrogate primary key by adding extra column: `id INTEGER AUTOINCREMENT`, and using it as primary key. In this case you will have both primary key, and no constraint on `q_id` field

Answer (score 1):

Remove `VALUES` from your SQL as the values come from SELECT in this case.

```
INSERT INTO trivia_data (
  q_id,
  q_text,
  q_options_1,
  q_options_2,
  q_options_3,
  q_options_4,
  q_options,
  q_difficulty_level,
  q_date_added
)
SELECT
  question_info.q_id,
  question_info.q_text,
  question_options_info.q_options_1,
  question_options_info.q_options_2,
  question_options_info.q_options_3,
  question_options_info.q_options_4,
  question_answer_info.q_options,
  question_info.q_difficulty_level,
  question_info.q_date_added
FROM question_info
JOIN question_options_info
  ON question_info.q_options_id = question_options_info.q_options_id
JOIN question_answer_info
  ON question_info.q_id = question_answer_info.q_id;
```

Comment: Removed the VALUES clause. And I just discovered that the data, I was trying to insert have redundant values for "question_info.q_id".

Comment: @FreakPirate not sure how to help without understanding the underlying data and where the uniqueness constraints are.

Comment: Its returning the error: "unique constraint failed:trivia_data.q_id:". Do you think that, I should remove the "PRIMARY KEY" constraint from the "trivia_data" table? Will the new definition of "trivia_data" be acceptable?

Comment: @FreakPirate It is likely that you have multiple records in joined tables that relate to q_id value.  In that case you should probably create an new unique primary key for that table and remove the unique constraint on q_id. I can't tell you if that would be "acceptable" though as I have no concept for how you are using this data.

Comment: I might not get into the mess to explain the concept of the underlying data. But in the nutshell "I am running a trivia API on [link](http://qserv.futuretraxex.com). And I have a database already running on the server. But that contains only 100 questions. So I want to merge that database with another one having thousands of questions. But definition does not match. So I was trying to adapt new database to original one". Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `VALUES` keyword. Try this:

```
INSERT INTO trivia_data (q_id, q_text, q_options_1, q_options_2, 
    q_options_3, q_options_4, q_options, q_difficulty_level, q_date_added)  
SELECT question_info.q_id, question_info.q_text, 
    question_options_info.q_options_1, question_options_info.q_options_2, 
    question_options_info.q_options_3, question_options_info.q_options_4, 
    question_answer_info.q_options, question_info.q_difficulty_level, 
    question_info.q_date_added FROM question_info 
    JOIN question_options_info on question_info.q_options_id = question_options_info.q_options_id 
    JOIN question_answer_info on question_info.q_id = question_answer_info.q_id;
```